# How do I use this code in a singleton in swift?

Tags: ios, singleton, swift3, alamofire

I have this code that I found here. Now I would like to know how to use it in a singleton. My understanding is if I use this code in a singleton I will be noticed if there is a change in the network status.

```
 func startNetworkReachabilityObserver() {
    let reachabilityManager = Alamofire.NetworkReachabilityManager(host: "www.google.com")
    reachabilityManager?.listener = { status in

        switch status {

        case .NotReachable:
            print("The network is not reachable")

        case .Unknown :
            print("It is unknown whether the network is reachable")

        case .Reachable(.EthernetOrWiFi):
            print("The network is reachable over the WiFi connection")

        case .Reachable(.WWAN):
            print("The network is reachable over the WWAN connection")

        }
    }

    // start listening
    reachabilityManager?.startListening()
}
```

Comment: You can simply make it a class method and use it as it is. No need to use a singleton I guess. Just call this function as soon as the application is launched.

Comment: No difference using it in a singleton as in an other class,  there's no magic in a singleton that means it has to go into a singleton, any class will do provided that class's lifetime is as long as you need the notification change to be for.

Comment: If I make a class method I'm not notified of any network status changes. In a singleton I will.

Answer (score 1):

Using a singleton is working as I long as you keep a reference of reachabilityManager

```
class NetworkStatus {
static let sharedInstance = NetworkStatus()

private init() {}

let reachabilityManager = Alamofire.NetworkReachabilityManager(host: "www.apple.com")

func startNetworkReachabilityObserver() {
    reachabilityManager?.listener = { status in

        switch status {

        case .notReachable:
            print("The network is not reachable")

        case .unknown :
            print("It is unknown whether the network is reachable")

        case .reachable(.ethernetOrWiFi):
            print("The network is reachable over the WiFi connection")

        case .reachable(.wwan):
            print("The network is reachable over the WWAN connection")

        }
    }
    reachabilityManager?.startListening()
}
```

}

So you can use it like this:

```
let networkStatus = NetworkStatus.sharedInstance

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    networkStatus.startNetworkReachabilityObserver()
}
```

You will be notified of any change in your network status.

Answer (score 0):

Hoist the variable into the class as a property.  Add a static shared property to make your class a singleton.

```
    class ReachabilityManager {
        private let networkReachabilityManager = NetworkReachabilityManager()
        static let shared = ReachabilityManager()
        private override init () {
            super.init()
            networkReachabilityManager?.listener = { status in
                //Post Notifications here
                }
            }
        }
        func startListening() {
            networkReachabilityManager.startListening()
        }
    }
```

The static properties are lazy by default so when you call ReachabilityManager.shared.startListening() it will instantiate the singleton the first time and subsequent calls use the existing shared instance.

Comment: Please make `init` `private` to assure we can not instantiate multiple singleton objects.